# complex DISTINCT, ORDER BY, WHERE sql select statement

Tags: sql, db2

I'm not very experienced with SQL (using DB2) and I am attempting to select distinct ID's which meet the following criteria:

```
select distinct a.ID
from DOGTOWN a
where a.DOGTOWNID > 0
  and (a.DELIVERYDATE < (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - 4680 DAYS))
order by a.ID ASC;
```

this returns me 4 records:

```
2100353550
2100353779
2100356002
2100356008
```

these returns are fine, however when I am attempting to do this:

```
select distinct a.ID 
from DOGTOWN a 
where 
    a.DOGTOWNID > 2100356002 
    and a.DELIVERYDATE < (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - 4680 DAYS) 
order by 
    a.ID ASC 
fetch first 3 rows only
```

i am expecting record 2100356008 in this scenario yet it returns an empty result set..

thanks to all the experts on this great community.

Comment: Can you explain your statement "2100356008 should be before 2100356002"?  That is not the way that I understand the ordering of values.  The values are ordered correctly.

Comment: What order do you want? Ascending (as in your code) or descending?

Comment: You do not use any aggregate functions. You have a simple *plain vanilla* query. What do you want to aggregate and how?

Comment: What is the difference between the `ID` column and the `DOGTOWNID` column?  Your first query returns values from the `ID` column, but in the second query you are comparing the values from `ID` with the column `DOGTOWNID`.

Answer (score 0):

nevermind guys, just comparing wrong id's.... answer is:

```
select distinct a.ID 
from DOGTOWN a 
where 
    a.ID > 2100356002 
    and a.DELIVERYDATE < (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - 4680 DAYS) 
order by 
    a.ID ASC 
fetch first 3 rows only
```

Comment: Given that my comment provided the correct answer, it's good practice to request that I provide the answer so you can accept it.